# Multiples images in jspdf

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pdf, jspdf

I'm trying to generate a pdfd file with multiples images, i can put one image in pdf document but i can't add more than one image,  i think that i need do a  loop but i don't know how :S,  somebody can help me to structure  my code and generate a pdf with multiple images?, this is my code..

```
function pruebaPDF(){
    html2canvas($(".jspdf2"),{
        onrendered: function(canvas){
            var height = $(".jspdf1").height();
            var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png"),
            doc = new jsPDF({
                orientation:'p',
                unit:'mm',
                format:'letter'
            });
            doc.addImage(data, 'PNG', 10, 6, 185, height);
            //doc.addPage();
            doc.save('tqwe.pdf');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new variable for your image and use the addImage() function:

```
var imgData = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'+ Base64.encode('yourimage.jpeg');
doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 15, 40, 180, 160);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The link below is a tutorial on how to make a form into a pdf.
that would include all the images / text boxes css ect...
this should hold all the answers you need.
If you need extra help dont hesitate i can guide you further.
http://www.techumber.com/2015/04/html-to-pdf-conversion-using-javascript.html

Comment: The problem i that i have two div,  i need to add these to the pdf, maybe i can use for example: for(var i=1;i<=2;i++) and invoke a  function to generate the canvas and finally implement addImage method

Comment: Just add the a wrapper over the 2 divs, when you get the content of the wrapper both images will be there.